# RubyOnRails: How do I use helper methods in Rails Console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, irb, actionviewhelper

Probably something wrong with my setup:

```
irb(main):001:0> truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", :length => 17)
NoMethodError: undefined method `truncate' for main:Object
        from (irb):1
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Looks like I cannot use any text helpers (both in irb and rails console).

What should I check?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Rails Console exposes the helper methods through the `helper` variable. Therefore, please, use this instead:

```
helper.truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", :length => 17)
```

for more, please read this [article on 37signals.com](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3176-three-quick-rails-console-tips)

Answer (score 4):

type following line into your rails console

`include ActionView::Helpers`

now your helpers are accessible during the entire rails console session and you can continue like…

`truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", :length => 17)`